# Problems with finding an average, max, number of certain variables, and counting number of loops, in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int userInput(int& Length, char& AuthorLevel);
int computePay(int& Length, char& AuthorLevel);

int main(void)
{
   int Length;      // The length of the story.
   int counter = 0;
   int numA = 0;
   int numB = 0;
   int numC = 0;
   char AuthorLevel;    // The level of the author.
   float PayOut;        // The final payout.
   float averagePayout = 0.0;
   float highestPayout = 0.0;

   while (1)
   {
      userInput(Length, AuthorLevel);
      if ( Length == -1 )
      {
         break; // Force the loop to quit, and the program to end.
      }
      computePay(Length, AuthorLevel);
   }

   return 0;
    } //end main()
//==================================================================

int userInput(int& Length, char& AuthorLevel )
{
   cout << "Please enter the word count of the story (-1 to stop): ";
   cin >> Length;
   if( Length != -1)
   {
      cout << "Now enter the author's level (A, B, or C): ";
      cin >> AuthorLevel;
      cout << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}

//==================================================================
int computePay(int& Length, char& AuthorLevel)
{
   float PayOut;        // The final payout.
   int numA = 0; // Number of A's that have been printed.
   int numB = 0; // Total number of B's.
   int numC = 0; // Number of C's.
   float averagePayout = 0.0;
   float highestPayout = 0.0;
   int counter = 0; // The number of times the program has ran.

   if(Length < 7500 || Length != -1)
   {
  PayOut = 0.08 * Length;
   }
   else if(Length < 8000)
   {
  PayOut = 600;
   }
   else if(Length < 17500)
   {
  PayOut = 0.075 * Length;
   }
   else if(Length < 19000)
   {
  PayOut = 1313;
   }
   else
   {
  PayOut = 0.07 * Length;
   };

   if (AuthorLevel == 'A' || AuthorLevel == 'a')
   {
      numA++;
      PayOut = 1.75 * PayOut;
   }
   else if(AuthorLevel == 'B' || AuthorLevel == 'b')
   {
      numB++;
      PayOut = 1.25 * PayOut;
   }
   else if (AuthorLevel == 'C' || AuthorLevel == 'c')
   {
      numC++;
      PayOut = 1.00 * PayOut;
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "That was not a valid input. Please try again." << endl;
   };

   counter++;
   cout << "The amount the author will make from the story will be: $" << PayOut;
   cout << endl << endl;
   cout << "The number of payments calculated is: " << counter << endl;
   cout << "The number of A's inputted: " << numA << endl;
   cout << "The number of B's inputted: " << numB << endl;
   cout << "The number of C's inputted: " << numC << endl;

   // FIXME
   averagePayout = (averagePayout += PayOut) / counter;
   // FIXME

   if(highestPayout < PayOut)
   {
      highestPayout = PayOut;
   }
   else if(highestPayout > PayOut)
   {
      highestPayout = highestPayout;
   }
   cout << "The highest payout so far has been: $" << highestPayout << endl;
   cout << "The average payout is: $" << averagePayout << endl << endl;
    }
    //===================================================
```

I'm trying to find the average payout, number of A's, B's, and C's outputted, highest payout, and number of loops, but none of that seems to be working at all. I've been working on this for hours, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Could anyone help?

Comment: Time to break out the old debugger and try stepping through the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason you define the variables for what you're counding (averages and counts) twice - once in `main` and the other time in `computePay`. You call `computePay` in a loop, and each time it is called, all the variables in it are re-initialized with zeros, thus you can't accumulate anything. There are two ways to fix this:

1. Pass the variables from `main` into `computePay` as references:

   ```
   int computePay(int& Length, char& AuthorLevel, int &averagePayout, int &highestPayout, <...>);
   //call it from main like:
   computePay(Length, AuthorLevel, averagePayout, highestPayout, <...>);
   ```
2. Make those variables `static` inside the function - that will cause them to keep their values between function calls

   ```
   int computePay(int& Length, char& AuthorLevel)
   {
      float PayOut;        // The final payout.
      static int numA = 0; // Number of A's that have been printed.
      static int numB = 0; // Total number of B's.
      <...>
   ```